# Computationally simple way to find N26 direction

Tags: computational-mathematics, computational-geometry, discrete-geometry

Assume we have an integral 3D grid $\mathbb{Z}^3$ and a set of line segments $V = \{((0, 0, 0), (x, y, z)): x, y, z \in \mathbb{Z} \land (x, y, z) \ne (0, 0, 0)\}$ from its origin to another grid point. I would like to find the closest (by Euclidian metric or by an angle between $v$ and $\vec{0p}$) single point $p \in N_{26}$, where $N_{26} = \{(x, y, z): x, y, z \in \{-1, 0, 1\} \land (x, y, z) \ne (0, 0, 0)\}$, for any $v \in V$. This is equivalent to finding a primary N26 direction of $v$. If there is a technical term for it, I would like to know.

I would like the method to be computationally efficient, perhaps avoiding using trigonometric functions. It doesn't have to be perfectly accurate: a few percent error is fine if it simplifies calculations.

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of generality assume the variable endpoint of $v$ is $(x,y,z)$ where $x\ge y\ge z\ge0$. There are only three points to test – $(1,0,0)$, $(1,1,0)$ and $(1,1,1)$.

Knowing that $u\cdot v=|u|\cdot|v|\cos\theta$, compute the three values
$$v\cdot(1,0,0)=x$$
$$\frac{v\cdot(1,1,0)}{\sqrt2}=\frac{x+y}{\sqrt2}$$
$$\frac{v\cdot(1,1,1)}{\sqrt3}=\frac{x+y+z}{\sqrt3}$$
The vector that gives the *largest* result (for $\cos$ is decreasing on $[0,\pi]$) is the correct primary $N_{26}$ direction.

Comment: What I had in mind is something really simple like: $f: (x, y, z) \rightarrow (\lfloor \frac{x}{m} \rceil, \lfloor \frac{y}{m} \rceil, \lfloor \frac{z}{m} \rceil)$ where $m = max(\lvert x\rvert, \lvert y\rvert, \lvert z\rvert)$ which has a few degrees error.